Question re: the screen magnifier in Ubuntu Accessibility Settings
I'm a visually impaired Linux user. I've been using Ubuntu on and off since 2012. My issue with Gnome always has been it's struggle with accessibility options and the lack of smoothness in it's default offerings.
My daily driver is a Linux Mint machine and the screen magnifier on that is as stable as the one on Windows. Wherever I leave the cursor on the screen, it stays there. On Ubuntu/Gnome regardless of where I aim the pointer to go, the zoomed in portion of the screen keeps switching elsewhere, and goes back to the cursor once I move it again. Also, while installing Ubuntu (24.04 is the ver. I'm on) in the USB Media boot and going thru the setup. If you enable the screen magnifier, which the installer offers right from the beginning of the install, the cursor lags so much that it's almost impossible to navigate.
Would love some insight.

What exactly is the question here? Do you wish to report a bug? Or are you looking for alternative desktop environments? Assuming you're using Cinnamon in Linux Mint, you could use Ubuntu Cinnamon.

I guess the question is why won't Ubuntu make an effort to smooth out it's accessibility settings? esp if they offer it front and center the moment you install the OS itself. I already do use Mint, and a few other distros. I'm putting it out there for Ubuntu to get better.

Maybe they just haven't run into this issue in their testing? Have you reported a bug yet? If not, how can anyone say why they aren't doing anything about something they aren't aware of?

By the way, this site is for general users of Ubuntu. Don't expect a question posted here to act as a bug report that will be acted on by Ubuntu developers. This is the wrong place to just put something out there "for Ubuntu to get better".
